# where can i find the Location of xdbconfig.xml in Oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

When I run on localhost:8080 I can find the file xdbconfig.xml
What if I want to edit the XML file and change port TNS listener.

I can edit through SQL Command line through:

```
Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8181);
```

But i want to get access to xdbconfig.xml and edit it manually.

Is there any way to get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

please try one of this :

This procedure updates metadata for a resource. The procedure takes in a resource identified by absolute path and the metadata in it to replace identified by its REF. It replaces that piece of metadata with user-defined metadata which is either in the form of a REF to XMLTYPE or an XMLTYPE.

Syntax

Can be used to update schema-based metadata only. The new metadata must be schema-based:

```
DBMS_XDB.UPDATERESOURCEMETADATA(
   abspath  IN VARCHAR2,
   oldmetadata    IN   REF SYS.XMLTYPE,
   newmetadata    IN   REF SYS.XMLTYPE)
```

Can be used to update schema-based metadata only. The new metadata must be schema-based or nonschema-based:

```
DBMS_XDB.UPDATERESOURCEMETADATA(
   abspath        IN   VARCHAR2,
   oldmetadata    IN   REF SYS.XMLTYPE,
   newmetadata    IN   XMLTYPE);
```

Can be used for both schema-based and nonschema-based metadata:

```
DBMS_XDB.UPDATERESOURCEMETADATA(
   abspath        IN   VARCHAR2,
   oldns          IN   VARCHAR2,
   oldname IN VARCHAR,
   newmetadata IN XMLTYPE);
```

Can be used for both schema-based or nonschema-based metadata. New metadata must be schema-based:

```
DBMS_XDB.UPDATERESOURCEMETADATA(
   abspath       IN   VARCHAR2,
   oldns         IN   VARCHAR2,
   oldname       IN   VARCHAR,
   newmetadata   IN   REF SYS.XMLTYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/appaman.htm#ADXDB5709):

> Oracle XML DB is managed internally through a configuration file, /xdbconfig.xml, which is stored as a resource in Oracle XML DB Repository. As an alternative to using Oracle Enterprise Manager to configure Oracle XML DB, you can configure it directly using the Oracle XML DB configuration file.
>
> The configuration file can be modified at run time. Updating the configuration file creates a new version of this repository resource. At the start of each session, the current version of the configuration file is bound to that session. The session uses this configuration-file version for its duration, unless you make an explicit call to refresh the session to the latest version.

And:

> You can access the Oracle XML DB configuration file, xdbconfig.xml, the same way you access any other XML schema-based resource in the hierarchy. It can be accessed using FTP, HTTP(S), WebDAV, Oracle Enterprise Manager, or any of the resource and Document Object Model (DOM) APIs for Java, PL/SQL, or C (OCI).
>
> For convenience, you can use PL/SQL package DBMS_XDB package for configuration access. ...

There is also [an example of how to modify it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/appaman.htm#CACHDDGI):

```
DECLARE
  v_cfg XMLType;
BEGIN
  SELECT updateXML(DBMS_XDB.cfg_get(), 
                   '/xdbconfig/descendant::ftp-port/text()',
                   '2121', 
                   '/xdbconfig/descendant::http-port/text()', 
                   '19090')
    INTO v_cfg FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_XDB.cfg_update(v_cfg);
  COMMIT; 
END;
/
```